# PowerShell - Test-Path ignoring file name

Tags: powershell

How can you use Test-Path (or any other function) to test if a folder exists - ignoring any trailing file names?

I need this to test if the target folder exists in order to write an output file to it. My script accepts a "full path" parameter like "**C:\Temp\myexport.csv**", and I only need to know that **C:\Temp** exists in order to be able to create the file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
$OutFile = "C:\Temp\myexport.csv"
$Dir=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($OutFile)

if(!(Test-Path $Dir)) { 
    Write-Host "Invalid path" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.. I didn't Google hard enough:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Temp\myexport.csv"
if(!Test-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $OutFile)) { 
    Write-Host "Invalid path" 
}
```

Comment: As a slight alternative, you could use, `If(!(Test-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $OutFile -Parent))) { Throw "$(Split-Path -Path $OutFile -Parent) does not exist." }`, you could even continue on from there with `Else { If(Test-Path -Path $OutFile) { Throw "$OutFile already exists." } }`.